# How can I use the unapproved comments list as a block?

Tags: blocks, comments

The unapproved comments list (available at `/admin/content/comment/approval`) allows me to perform bulk operations on comments such as deletion (which also gives me the option of reporting to Mollom) and publishing. I'd really like to have this on the dashboard itself — is there a way to replicate this admin page as a block so I can do so?

This is under Drupal 7.12.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use Views to list unpublished comments. That wouldn't provide batch operations, but it doesn't seem like there would be a simple way to do exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As @nkorth suggested, you can use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to list the unpublished comments. And using [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module you can add the same functionality on the comments administration page.