# How to create block with unapproved comments for dashboard?

Tags: 7, comments, dashboard

I have a question similar to [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31374/how-can-i-use-the-unapproved-comments-list-as-a-block): I'd like to add a block with an overview of unapproved comments on nodes to my dashboard and simply have the possibility to publish them (via a link or button).

How can I do that?

Comment: Why can't you try with same answer ?

Comment: Please provide more information: how is your situation different, and why answers to linked question does not work?

Comment: Well. I think @Елин Й's answer on the linked question may work, but I was just wondering if there isn't an easier solution. I only need a link or button to publish the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a simple solution, such as a link for approving a comment (no bulk operations), you can achieve this simply with Views.

Add a new field to your view of comments and select 'Comment: Approve link'. This will provide a link for approving the comment.

Comment: the approve link works all right, but every time I click it, I'm redirected to my localhost page. That's not a big disaster (the comment is published afterwards), but it's a bit annoying. Do you know how I can fix this? It would be perfect if the page just refreshed.

Comment: I've just tested it and it doesn't redirected to anywhere, it does only refreshes the page. There should be something other that causing the redirection.

Comment: You can try to change theme to bartik and disable related modules one by one. I've tested it on http://simplytest.me and modified the default view for 'Recent Comments' block.